# How to add border to simple tablelayout programmatically

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

How can I add borders to a `TableLayout` through code ?

**TableLayout in xml**

```
<TableLayout 
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</TableLayout>
```

**My code**

```
TableLayout prices = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
    prices.setStretchAllColumns(true);
    prices.bringToFront();
    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
        TableRow tr =  new TableRow(this);
        TextView c1 = new TextView(this);
        c1.setText(equipHere);
        c1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        c1.setTextSize(15);
        TextView c2 = new TextView(this);
        c2.setText("No of Days("+daysHere+")");
        c2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        c2.setTextSize(15);
        tr.addView(c1);
        tr.addView(c2);
        prices.addView(tr);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `Gradient` into `res\xml\table.xml` like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient   android:startColor="#C0C0C0" 
            android:endColor="#505050"
            android:angle="90"/>   
 <corners android:radius="2px" />
</shape>
```

And set to your `TableLayout` background

```
TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
table.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.xml.table));
```

And Programmatically you can achieve like:

```
  GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(
                GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,
                new int[] {Color.parseColor("#C0C0C0"), Color.parseColor("#505050")});
        gd.setGradientCenter(0.f, 1.f);
        gd.setLevel(2);
        table.setBackgroundDrawable(gd);
```

Answer (score 3):

Do following:

```
    GradientDrawable gd=new GradientDrawable();
    gd.setStroke(2, Color.BLACK);
            prices.setBackgroungDrawable(gd);
```

Answer (score 0):

create a xml file with the following code and place in the drawable folder

```
<corners android:radius="0dp" />
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
<stroke android:width="1sp" android:color="#e9e9e9" />
</shape>
```

and set the xml as a background resource  drawable for the table layout.