# Android table layout how to set border programatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I am creating a table layout programatically and displaying my data from database .
Each cell is a text view. I have given border color a black for each text view .This is not creating a perfect border for the table layout.

I want a perfect border to my table . How to do that programatically not using any xml files.

Code i am using to generate table layout

```
TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);

final GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
gd.setCornerRadius(5);
gd.setStroke(1, 0xFF000000);

TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());

TextView columsView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
columsView.setBackgroundDrawable(gd);
columsView.setText(""+c3.getString(j)); 
columsView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
tableRow.addView(columsView);   

tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
```

current output : check the image in the below link

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcmuI.jpg

Need perfect border for the table .How can i do this programatically?

Comment: Duplicate question....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21932479/how-to-add-border-to-simple-tablelayout-programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this out.

```
  TableLayout.LayoutParams tableRowParams =
  new TableLayout.LayoutParams
  (TableLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);

   tableRowParams.SetMargins(3, 3, 2, 10);

   row.LayoutParameters = tableRowParams;
```